# ListView item duplicate state of button to cell and vice-versa

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, state

I've been looking for solutions to share the state of child elements with the parent layout (item) in a ListView.

Explicitly, what I need is: when I press the cell, all child items are in the "pressed_state", but I also want is when I press a specific button in the cell, the entire cell becomes also pressed. However, I need `android:duplicateParentState="true"` for the latter to work, therefore `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` is impossible to define.

Do I need to use onTouchEvent for that specific button and set the pressed state programmatically to the cell and release it on press release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the onTouchListener for the specific button and not using both `android:duplicateParentState` nor `android:addStatesFromChildren` in the xml.

Here is what I have done in my CustomExpandableListAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /* code before */
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) convertViewNotNull.findViewById(R.id.ofButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerInCodeBefore);

    View.OnTouchListener onTouchCell = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    final int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            setPressedState(v, true);
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            setPressedState(v, false);
                            v.performClick();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
     button.setOnTouchListener(onTouchCell);
}
// code can be optimized
private void setPressedState(View v, boolean pressed) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();

    final int count = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = parent.getChildAt(i);
        view.setPressed(pressed);
        if (view instanceof RelativeLayout ||
            view instanceof LinearLayout) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;
            final int size = group.getChildCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                View child = group.getChildAt(j);
                child.setPressed(pressed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, it'll work.